# Opening URL address in browser when app clicked: Can't resolve symbol "MainActivity"

Tags: java, android, url, web

I am trying to create an android app which would open some URL address when it's clicked. I know there are couple of questions on similar topic but I couldn't create an app for this. After trying the app there were a couple of errors so I really need your help on this.

In AndroidManifest I get an error:
-Can't resolve symbol "MainActivity"

**In XML AndroidManifest is this code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test222.intenrt2" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In MainActiviy I get an error:
-Indentifier expected

-Invalid method delcaration; return type required

-Missing method boy or declare abstract

-Unkown class:'browserIntent'

-startAcitvity(browserIntent);

**In MainActivity.Java is this one**

```
package test222.intenrt2;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even seem to have a MainActivity class.
You should create a new class and name it **MainActivity**, extend it from **Activity** or **AppCompatActivity** in case you are using support library, in your new created class override **onCreate** method and move your code inside it. 
Last code should looks something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

    startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: thanks for that, it worked! Could you be so kind if you know when the page is open the app would close ?

Comment: I am glad it worked for your, in order to close your app your should finish all running activiteis, since you have only one simply call `finish()` at the end of your `onCreate()` method

Answer (score -1):

Your MainActivity should be extending Activity.

Then put your code in the onCreate method (You have it right on the class declaration not inside any method...).

Hope this helps.